# Why can I not create this implicitly-typed array?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
AccountMenuList = new[] 
{
    new {transKey = "MY_TICKETS", stateName="account.tickets", displayUrl="/account/tickets/"},
    new {transKey = "TRANSACTION_HISTORY", stateName = "account.transactionhistory", displayUrl = "/account/transactions"},
    new {transKey = "PAYIN", stateName = "account.payin",displayUrl = "/account/payin"},
    new {transKey = "PAYOUT", stateName = "account.payout", displayUrl = "/account/payout"},
    new {transKey = "TICKET_PAYOUT", stateName = "account.ticketpayout", displayUrl = "/account/ticketpayout"},
    new {transKey = "SETTINGS",stateName="default",displayUrl="default",SubMenuList=new[]{new{transKey = "something"}}}
};
```

But I get the following error:

> No best type found for implicitly-typed array

What's wrong? Can I fix this?

Comment: how defined `AccountMenuList`?

Comment: You get the error because the last anonymous type contains another property `SubMenuList`.

Comment: Is it possible to use this last anonymuus class with SubMenuList  or i need new anonymus class?

Comment: you can add this `SubMenuList` to all items

Comment: problem is that i need it only in last class...

Comment: You might want to consider creating a custom class instead of using anonymous classes.

Comment: how can i create custom class? can u give me an example ?

Comment: @None, then set that property to `null` in the other instances.

Comment: cannot assing null to anonymus type property

Comment: @Grundy how... i always get an erorrs

Comment: What exactly are you using this for.  If as Andriy Horen is guessing that it is for Json then use his answer.  If you need to access these values somewhere else in your code then you'd want a custom class or to set that property to something in the other anonymous classes.

Comment: im passing this value to angular and there i will put them in $scope and then i will print them somewhere else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong?

For every anonymous type compiler creates an actual type behind the scenes, and all of your objects having same declaration are of one type, except of the last one:

```
new {transKey = "SETTINGS",stateName="default",displayUrl="default",SubMenuList=new[] {new{transKey = "something"}}
```

How to fix it?

1. Create custom type for your menu items which makes more sense as later you may want to dynamically add/remove/filter them.
2. By adding `object` to your array initialization you can explicitly create an array of objects (with different anonymous type instances in it):

   ```
   var accountMenuList = new object[] 
   {
       new {transKey = "MY_TICKETS", stateName="account.tickets", displayUrl="/account/tickets/"},
       new {transKey = "TRANSACTION_HISTORY", stateName = "account.transactionhistory", displayUrl = "/account/transactions"},
       new {transKey = "PAYIN", stateName = "account.payin",displayUrl = "/account/payin"},
       new {transKey = "PAYOUT", stateName = "account.payout", displayUrl = "/account/payout"},
       new {transKey = "TICKET_PAYOUT", stateName = "account.ticketpayout", displayUrl = "/account/ticketpayout"},
       new {transKey = "SETTINGS",stateName="default",displayUrl="default",SubMenuList=new[]{new{transKey = "something"}}}
   };
   ```

Comment: Of course now you cannot use the values in the array without reflection or casting to dynamic.

Comment: Well, it will work only if you want to send it as json format

Comment: True, but I don't see anything about this being used for Json in the question.

Comment: Assuming code sample is a menu items collection for a web site will be serialized into json, i may be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `SubMenuList=new[]{new{transKey = "something"}}` from the last entry. All entries must have the same type of data for implicitly-typed arrays to work.

Comment: The OP states they need that.  It makes more sense to add the property to the other entries rather than remove it from the last one.

Comment: @juharr how can i assing null to anonyumus type property?

Comment: You are better off creating you own class instead of implicit types in these kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out. In this situation you may want to create a class.
Here is an example.

```
public class mydata
{
    public string transKey { get; set; }
    public string stateName { get; set; }
    public string displayUrl{ get; set; }
}
```

And then I'd use a list of type.

```
List<mydata>  myDataList = new List<mydata>();
```

To add to the list you can do like this.

```
// create object
mydata md = new mydata();
md.transKey = "MY_TICKETS";
md.stateName = "account.tickets";
md.displayUrl = "/account/tickets/";
// add to your list
myDataList.add(md);
```

And if you want to loop through myDataList you can do the following.

```
foreach(var items in myDataList)
{
    response.write(items.transkey);
}
```

I hope this helps.